# Whenever gem ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, rubygems

I created a simple task, which runs a method from the controller via gem "whenever".

#### schedule.rb

```
set :environment, :development
env :PATH, ENV['PATH']
set :output, { :error => "log/error.log", :standard => 'log/cron.log' }

every 2.minutes do 
   runner "ParserController.test1"
end
```

#### parser_controller.rb:

```
def self.test1
    puts "HELLO PARSER"
end
```

When I execute whenever --update-crontab and wait for 2 minutes I got an error in the log:

```
bundler: not executable: bin/rails
```

### Update:

I tried to run the command without cron and got 2 different results:

The first variant is

```
bundle exec bin/rails runner -e development 'ParserController.test1'

'bundler: not executable: bin/rails'
```

The second variant is

```
 bundle exec rails runner -e development 'ParserController.test1'
```

HELLO PARSER

Answer (score 0):

try adding `env :GEM_PATH, ENV['GEM_PATH']`

#### schedule.rb

```
set :environment, :development
env :PATH, ENV['PATH']
env :GEM_PATH, ENV['GEM_PATH']
set :output, { :error => "log/error.log", :standard => 'log/cron.log' }

every 2.minutes do 
   runner "ParserController.test1"
end
```